# How to get an SVG element from an object containing it without using .each( ..this)?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm sorry for the title, was not sure how to name it better.
So I define my SVG object like this:

```
var toolTip = settings.g
        .append("text")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
```

Later on, I need to get its BBox. However, I cannot call it on the toolTip object itself (toolTip.getBBox()). The only working solution I know is:

```
  toolTip.each(function (d, i){this.getBBox())
```

Why the call on the object does not work, and what is the right way here?

Comment: Tooltip is a d3 selection. You need a DOM element.